# Trello.Net authorisation works but can't access data once authorised

Tags: c#, trello, trello.net

I am new to `Trello.Net` and struggling a little with authorisation. I understand the process, of requesting a URL and then asking the user to browse to that URL to get a token.

The first problem is I am trying to write a process which runs automatically without any UI.  So I'm having to use a hard coded token, which I obtained by running this code to get a URL, which I then browse to manually. I would rather do this part automatically (get the resulting token programatically, not by having the user browse somewhere):

```
 ITrello trello = new Trello(Key);
    var url = trello.GetAuthorizationUrl("TrelloCapture", Scope.ReadWrite, Expiration.Never);
    Console.WriteLine(url);
```

This URL, when I browse to it, displays for me a token which, for now, I hardcoded into my application as follows:

```
var token = "[the token copied and pasted from the web page]"
```

I then authorise using:

```
trello.Authorize(token);
```

Which seems to work fine. Next I want to access some basic data, and this is where my second problem comes in.

```
// Get the authenticated member
Member me = trello.Members.Me();
Console.WriteLine(me.FullName);
```

`Members.Me()` returns `null` every time.  The same problem with `Cards.ForMe()` and other methods.  Everything is `null`.  Why?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Had a similar problem, but it was the Boards that were coming back null, not the Authorized user. Fixed it by tweaking the library a bit http://stackoverflow.com/a/34298404/1524502

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer.  I fixed it by getting the latest versions of these `NuGet` packages in my solution:

**Trello.Net**

**JSON.Net**

**RestSharp**

After getting those latest versions I was seeing proper values instead of `null` in the trello objects.

Hope this helps somebody who reads this.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, above answer helped me.
Though I couldn't get the latest but had to use:

"RestSharp" version="104.1
"Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.1"

Since The nuget also doesn't have the correct color enum i had to download the project and make my own changes.